# Is there a way to make a specific variable from a set an integer in Ampl?

Tags: ampl

```
set P;
set K;
set I:= {i in K};
set J:={j in P};
param C {P} >=0;
param A {K,P} >=0;
param B {K} >=0;
var X{j in P} >=0;
```

`P` consists of 4 set values, namely `sweatshirt-f`, `sweatshirtB/F`, `tshirtf` and `tshirtBF`, but I would like `sweatshirt-f` only to return an `integer`:

```
maximize f: sum{j in P} C[j]*X[j];
```

s.t. `Constraint {i in K}`:

```
sum{j in P} A[i,j]*X[j]<=B[i];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: declare all of them as integer, then relax integer constraints for the others:

```
var X{j in P} >=0 integer;
let {i in P: i <> "sweatshirt-f"} X[i].relax := 1;
```

Option 2: declare a dummy variable as integer, then constrain relevant value to match it:

```
var X{j in P} >=0;
var int_dummy integer;
s.t. force_integer: X["sweatshirt-f"] = int_dummy;
```

I'm not able to test those right now, so you may have to do a little debugging, but that should get you in the neighbourhood of a solution.